# clojure if-then-else?

Tags: if-statement, clojure

This should be a very trivial question. 
i am new to Clojure and writing this if-then-else based on: http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--%28if%20test%20then%20else?%29

However, I keep getting this error:

java.lang.Exception: Too many arguments to if (NO_SOURCE_FILE:424)

```
// This code has infinite recursion bugs; but it should compile!
(defn sumdown [sum x]
    (
    if (foo x) 
     (do
     (recur (+ sum x) (dec x))
     )
     else do(
        (recur (+ sum x) (dec x))
     )

     )
)
```

Comment: clojure parenthesis spaghetti is difficult to handle for me too.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the template:

```
(if test then else?)
```

both `then` and `else` don't represent keywords, but actual expressions. The `?` indicates the `else` expression is optional.

The test condition is evaluated and based on its value, the appropriate branch expression is evaluated and "returned" as the value of the entire if expression.

For example, this would define an absolute value function:

```
(defn abs [x]
  (if (< x 0)
    (- x)
    x))
```

Comment: 1. Please format you parens in the right way. 2. Your code would not work! You can not right 'x<0' and you can not write '-x' either, the code would look like this: (defn abs [x] (if (< x 0) (- x) x)). 3. If you write an 'if' you should always have a else-part, if you dont there is a spezall 'when' function.

Comment: @nickik: Sorry, I haven't written lisp in a while. Thanks :)

Comment: @nickik `if` does not always require an `else`, @QuicksilverJohny is correct in saying that ? implies an optional argument. `when` is a convenience function that allows the evaluation of multiple expressions as it's wrapped in an explicit `do`.

Comment: @toofarsideways I said you 'should' have an else part. If I read 'if' in Clojure I expect an else. It makes the code more readable to always use when.

Comment: @nickik So it's a stylistic choice? Isn't that limiting to people who don't think the exact same way as you? Personally I like the fact that the language gives some flexibility, without imposing a "one true way". I can understand that approach when writing libraries, which are publicly consumable. That said, I'll definitely look at `when` in future...

Comment: @toofarsideways Well yes a little bit. I just use the rule: "Use the function/macro that is closest to what you want". if/when is not a real issue more of a tool to teach people the rule.

Answer (score 7):

```
(defn sumdown [sum x]
  (if (foo x)
    (recur (+ sum x) (dec x))
    (recur (+ sum x) (dec x))))
```

This is the idiomatic way to write this code. I recommend a text editor / IDE with basic support for editing Lisp source (paren/bracket/brace matching).

Comment: Why did you leave the 'do' in?

Comment: @nickik thanks fixed, I didn't know if he had it there for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

The correct implementation of your sample, removing all redundant code, would be:

```
(defn sumdown
  [sum x]
  (recur (+ sum x) (dec x)))
```

Because both your 'then' and 'else' clauses are identical and the 'do's are redundant (and in any case the various 'do' forms are for side-effects).

Other conditionals to consider are: when, cond, condp and case.